# Maven set version for multi module project where not all modules parent-pom is the same

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have a project where I bundle several independant modules and manage them through one project
I want to be able to set their versions in one command, like:

```
mvn versions:set versions:commit -DnewVersion="$newVersion"
```

The structure is the following:

```
base-pom/
|-- module1
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- module2
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- module3
|   `-- pom.xml
 `-- pom.xml
```

`module1` is an infrastructure module and is used by both `module2` and `module3`
The trick is that module1 and module2 parent pom is indeed my `base-pom`, but module3 parent pom is something else, available in the repo and relevant only to `module3`.
Since both module2 and module3 needs module1, I found this "reactor" pattern the best option for me, as I can use it as a dependency without any issues.
The only problem I suffer from so far is that I want to be able to set the versions for all modules in one command from the base-pom directory.
It works perfectly fine for `base-pom`, `module1` & `module2`, but since `module3` parent is not `base-pom`, It will not update.

Is there any way around it, other than an intermediate pom file? Seems too hacky in my opinion.

Comment: It shows that your structure does not fit your needs, cause the module3 is not part of the multi module project (aggregator)..Does your `base-pom/pom.xml` contains a module reference to `module3`?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes because I want it to be built once I do mvn package for my base-pom

Comment: Than you shouldn't have a module as described `module3` which does not use a different parent...it should use `base-pom/` as parent...The question is why would you like to press it into this structure cause it sounds it does not belong there (separation of concerns)...

Comment: @buddy123 did you find a solution for this? I'm looking to do the same thing